# How to set date on jquery datepicker with java.util.Calendar class

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, struts2

I trying to edit an users profile. I have a "Date of birth" textfield, for which I use jqueryui date picker. At the server side I have struts2. Struts2 returns the date in java.util.Calendar object. I looking to find a way in which the default date of the datepicker can be set using this Calendar object.

Can this be done using struts-jquery plugin?

I tried like this

```
    $(function() {
        $("#txtDob").datepicker( "setDate" , <s:property value="#vendor.dateOfBirth" />);
        $( "#txtDob" ).datepicker({
            yearRange: '1930:-18',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
    });
```

Nothing is happening, even the datepicker isn't working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) you can use the value attribute from the DatePickerTag to set the value of your [DatePicker](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag).

```
<sj:datepicker value="%{vendor.dateOfBirth}" id="txtDob" name="dateOfBirth" label="Birthday" />
```

When using plain jQuery Ui and Struts2 you can use the Struts2 DateTag to set the Date.

```
$("#txtDob").val($.datepicker.formatDate(params.dateFormat, new Date(<s:date name="%{vendor.dateOfBirth}" format="yyyy, MM, dd" />)));
```

Note: You should init your datepicker before you set the Date via $(elem).datepicker( "setDate", val)

Comment: Thanks, its working great, I have on more query. I am able to get the date into the textfield but it not in the correct format. I want it to be in dd/MM/yyyy format. How can it be done.

Comment: Do you have used the <s:date /> tag? take a look at the format attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#yourinput").datepicker( "setDate" , "<% date_here %>" );
```